# Postgres why is swap-usage growing? How to reduce it? - AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, memory-management, amazon-rds

Having a postgres DB on AWS-RDS the `Swap Usage` in constantly rising.

Why is it rising? I tried rebooting but it does not sink. AWS writes that high swap usage is "*indicative of performance issues*"

I am writing data to this DB. CPU and Memory do look healthy:
[image]

To be precise i have a
`db.t2.micro`-Instance and at the moment ~30/100 GB Data in 5 Tables - General Purpose SSD. With the default postgresql.conf.

The swap-graph looks as follows:

[image]

Swap Usage warning:

[image]

Comment: Without knowing your postgresql.conf it is hard to tell. Ussually it is a complex query with aggregation when lots of in-memory computation is tried to be performed by PostgreSQL.   However 13.00MB of SWAP is not a problem at all, especially on SSD, even though they are general purpose. I would not bother. 

I have 378Gb of operating memory for PostgreSQL, and it somehow uses 36.8M of swap - that is not a problem for me at all!

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin: Thanks. That helps me a lot. I Do use the standard RDS postgresql.conf if that helps

Comment: Well It seems that your queries are using a memory volume over your available.  So you should look at your queries execution plan and find out largest loads.  That queries exceeds the memory available for postgresql. Usually over-much joining (i.e. bad database structure, which would be better denonarmalized if applicable), or lots of nested queries, or  queries with IN clauses - those are typical suspects.  I guess amazon delivered as much as possible for postgresql.conf and those default values are quite good for this tiny machine.

Comment: But once again unless your swap size is not exceeding your available memory and your are on a SSD - there would be not that much harm of it.

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin: Can you please write this as answer then i can accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well It seems that your queries are using a memory volume over your available. So you should look at your queries execution plan and find out largest loads. That queries exceeds the memory available for postgresql. Usually over-much joining (i.e. bad database structure, which would be better denonarmalized if applicable), or lots of nested queries, or queries with IN clauses - those are typical suspects. I guess amazon delivered as much as possible for postgresql.conf and those default values are quite good for this tiny machine.

But once again unless your swap size is not exceeding your available memory and your are on a SSD - there would be not that much harm of it

Answer (score 2):

check the

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

and see if which process taking long and how many processes sleeping, try to change your RDS DBparameter according to your need.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you ran out of memory. db.t2.micro has only 1GB of RAM. You should look in htop output to see which processes takes most of memory and try to optimize memory usage. Also there is nice utility called pgtop (http://ptop.projects.pgfoundry.org/) which shows current queries, number of rows read, etc. You can use it to view your postgress state in realtime. By the way, if you cannot install pgtop you can get just the same information from posgres internal tools - check out documentation of postgres stats collector https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html

Actually it is difficult to say what the problem is exactly but db.t2.micro is a very limited instance. You should consider taking a biggier instance especially if you are using postgres in production.